# Why does Laravel give me an infinite redirect?

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am in the process of converting my personal web site over to Laravel. I placed the old site into the `public` folder, and have the following catch-all route to fall back on the old site (placed at the *end* of my routes file):

```
Route::any('{all}', array('use' => Redirect::to('{all}')));
```

I have been converting over a page at a time, and so far everything has gone well. However, after converting one page, `humor`, Firefox gave me this error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

I checked the Apache log, and noticed that it alternated several times between the following:

> "GET /humor HTTP/1.1"
>   "GET /humor/ HTTP/1.1"

The relevant route is:

```
Route::resource('humor', 'HumorController');
```

The controller method is:

```
public function index() {  
  return View::make("humor.index");  
}
```

The view is:

```
@extends('master')

@section('title')
  Humor
@stop

@section('content')
  [snip]
  <p><a href="/humor/jokes.php">Jokes</a></p>
  <p><a href="/humor/jokes_new.php">Jokes (Testing)</a></p>
  <p><a href="/humor/xkcd.php">xkcd</a></p>
@stop
```

Those links are currently to pages on the old site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out by noticing that if I attempted to access a folder on my old site in the form `/some/folder`, it would automatically redirect to `/some/folder/` and show the contents. Because the `humor` folder still existed on my old site (in the `public` folder), Apache tried to add the trailing `/` and show the contents. However, my `.htaccess` file for Laravel is set to remove the trailing `/`, thus they fought with each other and caused an infinite loop.

I fixed this by renaming the `humor` directory in `public` to `humor_old` and updating the relevant links.

I have answered my own question here because when I searched SO for Laravel and the Firefox error, I came up with 4 results, all differing from my problem.